# Getting a list item using record's attribute as an index

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

How can one get access to an item inside a list using one of the attributes as an index into that list?

Here's the test schema:

```
create class Test extends V
insert into Test content {"items": [ { "name": "Item 1" }, { "name": "Item 2" } ], "selected": 1 }
```

Suppose new records RID is #100:0, then the following queries **do not work**:

```
select items[ @this.selected ].name from #100:0
select items[ eval('@this.selected') ].name from #100:0
```

What am I doing wrong? Im on orient 2.1.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is the solution which works for multiple records:

```
select items[$i].name from Test let $i = eval('selected')
```

NOTE: However, it still makes sense if attributes could be used directly to index elements in queries that reference embedded lists. This might probably be available in later versions of OrientDB

Answer (score 2):

I have this simple structure:

[image]

To retrieve the results you're looking for, I used this **query**:

```
select items[$i.sel].name from Test
let $i = (select eval('selected') as sel from #12:0)
```

**Output**:

```
----+------+------
#   |@CLASS|items
----+------+------
0   |null  |Item 1
1   |null  |Item 3
----+------+------
```

**EDITED**

Or **this**:

```
select items[$i.sel].name from Test
let $i = (select eval('selected') as sel from #12:1)
```

**Output**:

```
----+------+------
#   |@CLASS|items
----+------+------
0   |null  |Item 2
1   |null  |Item 4
----+------+------
```

**2nd EDIT**

**Query 1**:

```
select items.name[$i.sel] from Test
let $i = (select *, eval('selected') as sel from 12:0)
where @this in $i
```

**Output**:

```
----+------+------
#   |@CLASS|items
----+------+------
0   |null  |Item 1
----+------+------
```

**Query 2**:

```
select items.name[$i.sel] from 12:1
let $i = (select eval('selected') as sel from 12:0)
```

**Output**:

```
----+------+------
#   |@CLASS|items
----+------+------
0   |null  |Item 3
----+------+------
```

**Query 3**:

```
select items[$i.selected].name from Test let $i = selected unwind items
```

**Output**:

```
----+------+------
#   |@CLASS|items
----+------+------
0   |null  |Item 1
1   |null  |Item 2
2   |null  |Item 3
3   |null  |Item 4
----+------+------
```

Hope it helps

Comment: this is partially correct, but what I actually need is to get a selected item's name for *each* record. However, that `let` statement has actually made me realize how to do this query: `select items[$il].name from Test let $i = eval('selected')`. If you mod your answer, i'd be glad to mark it as correct ))

Comment: both queries from your 2nd edit wont work properly just for the reason that your `let` statement contains a query that targets only the first record from the class `Test` The goal is to get selected names for each record in class Test...

Comment: Hi, can you explain better please ? Because if you want to get all `items.name` at index `0` or `1` the first two queries retrieve the correct `name` in all of the records of the class Test...

Comment: Index 0: `items.name = 'item 1` and `items.name = 'item 3`  -               Index 1: `items.name = 'item 2` and `items.name = 'item 4`

Comment: Try this on your test records: `select items[$i].name from Test let $i = eval('selected')` and then compare it to result of your first query: `select items[$i.sel].name from Test
let $i = (select eval('selected') as sel from #12:0)`

Comment: You are selecting item name from each record, but your ` $i` will always be `0`, because you are doing `let $i = (select eval('selected') as sel from #12:0)`. I what i need is to get item name for each record **indexed by the `selected` attribute from that same record**

Comment: Hey @AVK. So this does work. 

`select items[$i].name from Test let $i = eval('selected')`

Comment: yes it does. Just wanted to leave this answer to @LucaS, but im going to have to answer myself now i guess

Comment: hehe...I was about to steal an answer.

Comment: It is probably better, when you answer it yourself.

Comment: ))) you could and i wouldnt mind as long as you have provided a nice explanation along with it

Comment: Hi AVK, sorry I got busy and I had no chance to answer. I thought you wanted to retrieve the items.name separately and I implemented this query `select items[$i.selected].name from Test let $i = selected unwind items` but I lost my chance :)